# How to merge one image in center of the other image in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have one image which is thumbnail for the video.I want to add the play image in center of that thumbnail image so that i can identify it's a video.Please tell how can i do that.I am using below code to merge images but that does not work for me.

```
- (UIImage *) getMergeImage:(UIImage *)parentImage childImage:(UIImage *)childImage
{
    UIImage *bottomImage =  parentImage;//background image
    UIImage *image       =  childImage;//foreground image

    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(bottomImage.size.width, bottomImage.size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);

    // Use existing opacity as is
    [bottomImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];

    // Apply supplied opacity if applicable
    // Change xPos, yPos if applicable
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(18,18,36,36) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: do u want put child image at the center of parent image ?

Comment: Yes. that's exactly i want

Comment: here x & y is 18,18 how can i make it as center of the image.

Comment: @deepakkumar Did my code helped ??

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use two ImageViews

```
- (UIImage *) getMergeImage:(UIImage *)parentImage childImage:(UIImage *)childImage{

CGSize size = CGSizeMake(parentImage.size.width, parentImage.size.height);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

[image1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,size.width, size.height)];
[image2 drawInRect:CGRectMake( ((size.width - childImage.size.width) / 2 ),((size.height - childImage.size.height) / 2 ),image2.size.width, image2.size.height)];

UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return finalImage;
}
```

Comment: What's the point of the `image1`, and `image2` variables? It actually makes the rest of the method unclear. Stick with the original `parentImage` and `childImage` variables.

Comment: Updated the code to use parentImage and childImage instead of  image1 and image2.

Comment: image 1 and image 2？

Answer (score 0):

I fix the image1 and image2 and add autoreleasepool to avoid the memory issue:

```
- (UIImage *)getMergeImage:(UIImage *)parentImage childImage:(UIImage *)childImage{
@autoreleasepool {
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(parentImage.size.width, parentImage.size.height);
    
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    
    [parentImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,size.width, size.height)];
    [childImage drawInRect:CGRectMake( ((size.width - childImage.size.width) / 2 ),((size.height - childImage.size.height) / 2 ),childImage.size.width, childImage.size.height)];
    
    UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    
    return finalImage;
}
```

}